# How do you purify gases formed in electrolysis with a potassium hydroxide electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, home-experiment, safety, purification

I am interested in the $\ce{KOH}$ vapor that is released with my gasses during electrolysis.

I have two questions.

What would be the best place to start research on the $\ce{KOH}$ vapor produced in electrolysis and how to separate the $\ce{KOH}$ vapor formed.

I was thinking about filters, or bubblers that require constant water replacement. For me, a bubbler is a jar with a gas inlet at the bottom and gas collection at the top.

Also I have no clue on what type of filter to use since I don't know where to start research on $\ce{KOH}$ vapor.

My goal is to make the gases safer by eliminating most of the $\ce{KOH}$ vapor. I will probably use a pH testing paper to test the air to see if $\ce{KOH}$ vapor is present.

Comment: What type of electrolysis are you talking about? Aqueous KOH or molten KOH? If you talking about aqueous, then KOH vapor can be called nonexistent, on the other hand molten KOH well that is another story.

Comment: aqueous KOH, I am not even heating up the electrolysis. Thank you for the info I could not find it anywhere. I will still use 2 bubblers and replace water frequently. As well as testing the air for KOH with ph paper.

Comment: To be precise, i have no proof of what i said, but is an intuition from my experience and sense. It could be possible for KOH vapors to escape, but based on its hygroscopic nature it is neglectable. It also could be predicted that if a little KOH vapor would escape it would react with atmospheric CO2 to produce K2CO3 and water, decreasing its basicity in orders of magnitude rendering it more safe.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on youtube about hydrogen and oxygen (HHO) production from electrolysis. Mostly they use baking soda, NaOH rarely KOH for the electrolyte. In every video there are instruction that you have to attach a water bubbler to secure burnback. The water bubbler may probably filter the NaOH and KOH vapors if there any measurable quantity at all present.

Comment: I very much so appreciate the help. Your expertise is much better than my small chemistry knowledge. My design is all about safety and i though koh being a better electrolyte would allow for less to be used. there for less to be cleaned up in a spill and less danger overall. Should I be worried that Everyone else is using NaOH or did I just choose a strange electrolyte. If this is too much to ask you have been an amazing help and thank you very much. I was very worried about koh mist. I will still proceed with caution.

Comment: I think NaOH is just more commercial than KOH simple as that, it makes no difference. In theory you would be better off with NaOH since its molecular weight is less, so you need less NaOH for the same conductivity than KOH. (Also the conductivity is heavily factored on the OH- ion, not the cation, thats why NaHCO3 and Na2CO3 conduct less, since they are far less basic = less OH- molecules, but safer for sure)

Comment: If you want to take it further for better conductivity in exchange for lower shelf life I reccomend sulfuric acid, since H+ has the highest mobility (higher than OH-) yielding higher conductivity. The downside is that there will be surely sulfuric acid vapors escaping and generally speaking more corrosive to metals than alkali hydroxides.

Comment: My first electrolysis prototype was sulfuric acid. It ended up being way too expensive and unsafe. Finding materials that Sulfuric acid wouldn't destroy was difficult. I choose hdpe and couldn't make an airtight seal due to the same reason I picked it. The chemical inertness stopped all my adhesives from working. Even the poly welds failed. **Thank you for all the help Andrew**. I am close to being done and am just hoping at this point I don't run into any major design flaws. Success or not the knowledge and experienced I have gained is more valuable than the hydrogen generator.